# Qt: How to display selected text in an inactive window

Tags: c++, qt

I have an inactive `QMainWindow` with a `QTabWidget` as `CentralWidget` which holds multiple `QPlainTextEdits`. Beside that I have a seperate `QWidget` flagged with `Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint` and `Qt::Tool` which I want to use as a find/replace tool for the `QPlainTextEdits`.

Now when I use the tool widget the `QMainWindow` is shown as inactive like it should and the selection background of the selected text in the active `QPlainTextEdit` is rendered as inactive (slightly grey) but I want the selection to be rendered like the `QMainWindow` would be active, with the default selection color w/o loosing the focus on the tool widget.

How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something this:

```
QPalette p = myInactiveWidget->palette();
for (int colorRole=0; colorRole<QPalette::NColorRoles; colorRole++) p.setColor(QPalette::Inactive, colorRole, p.color(QPalette::Active, colorRole));
myInactiveWidget->setPalette(p);
```

That should make (myInactiveWidget)'s inactive-color-palette the same as its active-color-palette, so that it no longer looks inactive.  Or if all you care about is the color of the text-selection-block, then this would probably be sufficient:

```
QPalette p = myInactiveWidget->palette();
p.setColor(QPalette::Inactive, QPalette::Highlight, p.color(QPalette::Active, QPalette::Highlight));
p.setColor(QPalette::Inactive, QPalette::HighlightedText, p.color(QPalette::Active, QPalette::HighlightedText));
myInactiveWidget->setPalette(p);
```